# asp.net vs. xcode button click

Tags: xcode, ibaction

I just started learning objective c and iphone development. Coming from an asp.net and web development, I am so lost with xcode.

In asp.net, you create a button, then you can simply click on it and it takes you right to the button event. Vs. Xcode, you create a button, then you will have to create an outlet in the header file, property, IBaction. Then in the implementation (.m) file, you create the click event method for that button. After that, you have to create an outlet reference of that button touch to that event by draging...

Just out of curiosity, is there any shortcuts or easier way to do this like asp.net? Without having to create outlet, property, etc. If there are any ways to eliminate some steps would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform action only click button you don't need to declare UIButton IBOutlet.

Just simply drag UIButton object on your view then declare & implement IBAction method in your class. Then make connection between action and button.

There is not shortcut in xcode for this if you want to interact with interface objects in your controller class you need to declare them as property and implement using @synthesize